# How do I loop a qqplot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I am trying to create a function that loops through the columns of my dataset and saves a qq-plot of each of my variables. I have spent a lot of time looking for a solution, but I am an R novice and haven't been able to successfully apply any answers to my data. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

There error I am give is this, "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'i' not found"

```
library(ggplot2)
QQPlot <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
    nm <- names(x)
    for (i in names(mybbs)) {
            plots <-ggplot(mybbs, aes(sample = nm[i])) + 
                    stat_qq()
            ggsave(plots, filename = paste(nm[i], ".png", sep=""))
    }
}

QQPlot(mybbs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because you are trying to pass a string as a variable name. Use `aes_string()` instead of `aes()`

Moreover, you are looping over names, not indexes; `nm[i]` would work for something like `for(i in seq_along(names(x))`, but not with your current loop. You would be better off replacing all `nm[i]` by `i` in the function, since what you want is the variable name.

Finally, you use `mybbs` instead of `x` inside the function. That means it will not work properly with any other data.frame.

Here is a solution to those three problems:

```
QQPlot <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  for (i in names(x)) {
    plots <-ggplot(x, aes_string(sample = i)) + 
      stat_qq()
    #print(plots)
    ggsave(plots, filename = paste(i, ".png", sep=""))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand my errors and for the code to fix them! It worked like a charm!